# Freeing structure of structures that were allocated by malloc causes error?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, free

So I'm trying to make a game using C and I have the following types :

```
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
} vector;

typedef struct{
    vector *vec;
    void (*update)();
} velocity;

typedef struct{
    vector *vec;
    velocity *vel;
    void (*move)();
} hero;
```

And here is the following code that is giving me an error:

```
hero *h;
// allocate memory for hero 
h = malloc(sizeof(hero*));
// allocate memory for velocity
h->vel = malloc(sizeof(velocity*));

// initialize vectors
h->vec = malloc(sizeof(vector*));
h->vel->vec = malloc(sizeof(vector*));

free(h->vec); // free hero vector
free(h->vel->vec); // free velocity vector
free(h->vel); // free velocity
free(h); // free hero
```

For some reason, free(h->vel) gives me an error when trying to free the velocity. Why does this happen? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think you mean allocating of an object of the type hero instead of the pointer  hero * in this statement h = malloc(sizeof(hero));

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I'm assuming it's a segmentation fault, but I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
h = malloc(sizeof(hero*));
```

You're allocating space for a **pointer to hero**, not an **instance of hero**.

As a result, you're not allocating enough memory for your structs, and writing to the fields of the struct writes past the end of allocated memory.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your particular case manifests as a crash when calling `free`.

Removed the `*` operator from the `sizeof` expressions to allocate enough space for an instance of your structs:

```
hero *h;
// allocate memory for hero 
h = malloc(sizeof(hero));
// allocate memory for velocity
h->vel = malloc(sizeof(velocity));

// initialize vectors
h->vec = malloc(sizeof(vector));
h->vel->vec = malloc(sizeof(vector));
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `h` is declared as `hero *h;` then you allocate enough memory for a *pointer* to `hero`, not the actual `hero` structure. Change to

```
h = malloc(sizeof *h);
```

Same with the other allocations.

Because you allocate to little memory, your assignments to the members of `h` will lead you to write data out of bounds of your allocated memory, and that will in turn lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = malloc(sizeof(hero*));
```

you just alloc memory for the size of pointer not the structure itself

All other as well

For the macro fans:

```
#define SMALLOC(x)      (malloc(sizeof *(x)))

hero *h;
h = SMALLOC(h);
h->vel = SMALLOC(h->vel);

// initialize vectors
h->vec = SMALLOC(h->vec)
h->vel->vec = SMALLOC(h->vel->vec);
```